# Redirecionar acesso para um subdomínio

Tags: htaccess

Tenho o seguinte subdomínio: **http://projetos.site.com.br**. Como eu faria para que o usuário ao digitar: **www.site.com.br/projetos**, fosse redirecionado para o subdomínio informado? Criei dentro do diretório **projetos** a seguinte regra no **.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.site.com.br/projetos
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://projetos.site.com.br/$1 [L]
```

Mas não funcionou! No CPanel consigo redirecionar o subdomínio para um outro diretório, mas não o contrário. Não conheço muito htaccess. Tentei também dessa forma:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com.br/projetos$
RewriteRule (.*) http://projetos.site.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
```

e

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com.br/projetos$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.com.br/projetos$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://projetos.site.com.br/ [R=301,L]
```

Mas também não funcionaram! Coloquei na pasta raiz esse htaccess e nada!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, peço desculpas por não ter funcionando Não consegui etender por que não fucionou mais certa vez eu precisei fazer algo parecido e deu certo dessa forma

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^antigoendereco.com$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.antigoendereco.com$

RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.novoendereco.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(Nota: Apenas em servidores com Linux. Se utiliza o WordPress.com ou Blogger, não consegue redireccionar desta maneira.)

Teste para ver se resolver seu problema e volte a comentar Espero ter ajudado.